# problem in finding the nearest places in google map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

i want to do one application which searches for the nearset stores or hotels in iphone. for that i found a link in google http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearches  i studied that document and i used the example link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key the key used is my key. but this link is not working for me to see the xml in the browser. i got the error as

```
<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

how to see this xml document fullly ... any help...

EDIT: Deleted my key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your API key. Follow the instructions on that page you linked to and go to API Access on https://code.google.com/apis/console/

BTW, you shouldn't post your API key on a public website.